# Как реализовать матричную пирамиду? Фреймворк Laravel

Tags: laravel

Доброго времени суток, пытаюсь реализовать простую Матричную пирамиду.
Логика алгоритма следующая, у каждого пользователя может быть только 3 подписчика, в случае если появляется 4-ый подписчик, он становится подписчиком подписчика под номером 1.
Условная таблица вот такая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
То есть схема заполнения пирамиды должна быть сверху вниз - слева направо, предположим если зарегистрируются новые подписчики с id 13, 14, 15 они встанут вот сюда
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пытался сделать через циклы foreach, но непонятно как реализовать глубинное множество, их будет неограниченное кол-во

```
public function matrix($user, $follower)
{
    $followers = UserFollower::where('user_id', $follower->user->id)
        ->get();
    if($followers->count() < 2):
        $follower = new UserFollower([
            'user_id' => $follower->user->id,
            'follower_id' => $user->id
        ]);
        $follower->save();
        return 'success';
    else:
        foreach($followers as $follower):
            if($follower->users->count() == 2):
                continue;
            else:
                $follower = new UserFollower([
                    'user_id' => $follower->user->id,
                    'follower_id' => $user->id
                ]);
                $follower->save();
                return 'success';
            endif;
            $this->matrix($user, $follower);
        endforeach;
    endif;
}
public function store(Request $request)
{
    /* Регистрируем пользователя */
    $user = New User($request->all());
    $user->save();
    /* Матрица */
    $followers = UserFollower::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->get();
    if($followers->count() < 2):
        $follower = new UserFollower([
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'follower_id' => $user->id
        ]);
        $follower->save();
    else:
        foreach($followers as $follower):
            if($follower->users->count() == 2):
                continue;
            else:
                $follower = new UserFollower([
                    'user_id' => $follower->user->id,
                    'follower_id' => $user->id
                ]);
                $follower->save();
                break;
            endif;
            if($this->matrix($user, $follower) == 'success') break;
        endforeach;
    endif;
    /* Редирект */
    return Redirect::back()
        ->with('message', 'Статус выполнения: 200');
}
```

Comment: Готов хорошо заплатить за помощь в реализации

Comment: тут простая рекурсия, foreach у тебя ничего не выйдет, посмотри рекурсивную реализацию дерева бинарного, только сделай проверку и будет тебе счастье

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за отклик. Подскажите пожалуйста где можно посмотреть примеры бинарного дерева?

Comment: Если не затруднит, можете добавить в ответ пример просто обхода массива рекурсивного, буду премного благодарен

Comment: Сейчас время мало, возможно позже, но вспомнил про такой [пакет](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset)

Comment: Вот [тут есть пример](https://www.sitepoint.com/data-structures-2/) хороший

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, задача сформулирована не полностью.

С простенькой рекурсией можно сделать следующее: если у меня нет свободного места, то отдать новенького моему первому.. и дальше по рекурсии: если у него нет свободного места, то отдать его первому. Но в этом случае, будет расти только одна из веток вглубь, в то время как линии будут оставаться пустыми.
Это простая задача. Но это ли на самом деле нужно?

Вероятно, новенького надо добавлять на "ближайшее" свободное место. А какое место является ближайшим? В простейшем случае, это первое свободное при последовательном обходе всех подуровней. А в более сложном, надо учитывать количество уже имеющихся подписчиков. То есть, может быть так, что у моего первого всего трое, но они занимают все места на его первом уровне, а у моего второго всего один, но у этого одного сотня в глубину.

В зависимости от того, куда надо добавлять, будет и разный подход к решению задачи. Возможно, каждый раз искать "ближайшее" место будет "невыгодно".

Плюс, не ясна Ваша схема данных.
Что за `UserFollower`? Можно хранить ссылку на "родителя" или, если последователей максимум трое (и это не будет меняться), то можно просто хранить три ссылки на последователей.

В самом простом случае, можно сделать как-то так:

В контроллере (конечно, нужна валидация...):

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $newUser = User::create($request->all());
    Auth::user()->addFollower($newUser);
}
```

В моделе:

```
public function follower1()
{
    // предположим, что мы храним ссылки на наших последователей.. это никак не влияет на решение..
    // главное, чтобы можно было получить первого потомка
    return User::find($this->follower1_id);
}

public function addFollower(User $user)
{
    if (is_null($this->follower1_id)) {
        $this->follower1_id = $user->id;
        $this->save();
    } elseif (is_null($this->follower2_id)) {
        $this->follower2_id = $user->id;
        $this->save();
    } elseif (is_null($this->follower3_id)) {
        $this->follower3_id = $user->id;
        $this->save();
    } else {
        // рекурсивный вызов функции
        $this->follower1()->addFollower($user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за отклик. Добавил код, рекурсия срабатывает так как мне нужно до 3-го уровня, дальше уже ничего не происходит. Можете что нибудь порекомендовать с моим кодом?

Comment: 1. Не понятно что за `UserFollower`. Вы пытаетесь реализовать связь один ко многим через вспомогательную табличку? 2. Много повторяющегося кода. В главной функции, в "разделе" матрица должно быть только `$this->matrix($user, Auth::user());`. И тд 3. Так что же должно быть: расти вглубь через первого или последовательно проходить все линии и искать первое свободное место?

Comment: UserFollower это грубо говоря обращение к таблице user_followers

Comment: Последовательно проходить все линии и искать первое свободное место

Comment: Если `user_followers` нужна только для хранения связи один пользователь - три последователя, то я бы отказался от этой таблички. Можно хранить ссылку на "родителя", а можно хранить три ссылки на последователей.

Comment: Добавил в ответ слегка измененный Ваш код. Проверьте. Надеюсь, будет работать.

Comment: Выдает ошибку array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

Comment: А, ну да. Там же у вас `users` в `followers` сидят. И только у них `id`шки. Говорю же, лишняя эта табличка. Только спотыкаемся об неё )). Думаю, можно эти `id`шки пособирать и в предыдущем цикле...

Comment: Подскажите плс что в коде и на что заменить?) Спасибо большое)

Comment: А так работает? Не видно весь код.. да голова другим забита.. в общем думать не хочется ))

Comment: Бесконечный цикл запускается

Comment: Подумаю. Эта табличка весь мозг выворачивает. Она точно нужна?

Comment: Не знаю) думаю нет

Comment: Есть три правильных, на мой взгляд, варианта. • Добавить три поля в табличку пользователей (`follower1_id`, `follower2_id`, `follower3_id`) и использовать предложенный мной вариант. • Если планируется изменить число последователей, то добавить поле `parent_id` в табличку пользователей и по нему искать последователей. • Если не хочется вносить изменения в табличку пользователей, то можно создать табличку для хранения матрицы `user_id`, `follower1_id`, `follower2_id`, `follower3_id` или `user_id`, `parent_id` (то, что есть сейчас, но вложить другой смысл и связи).

Comment: Можете написать мне на почту stackove@yandex.kz - еще остались вопросы) за помощь отблагодарю)